# Can ofstream be used for printing on a printer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, printing, printers

Can `ofstream` be used to write on a printer?

eg:

```
string nameOfPrinter = "xyz";
ofstream onPrinter(nameOfPrinter);
onPrinter << "Printing.... ";
```

If I do as above will I get the output by the printer *(on the paper)* ?

**If not, why I won't get the output? Please suggest a way to print using a printer.**

*I am targeting the Windows platform (32bit)*

Comment: Don't forget that `ofstream` doesn't have a constructor that takes `std::string`!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/lineprint.aspx?print=true

Comment: @Tomalak: unless you have a c++0x capable Standard library :)

Comment: Did you check the formfeed (see my example) ?

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to have your printer associated with LPT1 and a printer which support formfeeds.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    ofstream printer ("LPT1");
    if(!printer)
    {  return 1;
    }

    printer.puts("Test Test Test\n");
    printer.putc('\f');
    printer.close();
    return 0;
}
```

LPT1 is also a file name in windows. But as known it is a reserved filename. So it will not be possible to have more than one file with the name LPT1. And this file is already managed by windows.

See for [reserved filenames](http://www.webmasterworld.com/microsoft_windows_os/3128786.htm)

Comment: Writing to LPT1 is not a proper way to print on Windows, and is unlikely to work.

Comment: Given the requirements stated at the top it will probably.

Comment: If you go back in time, probably.

Comment: Thats not the point the question was "can ofstream be used for printing" and thats in my understanding a valid answer to it.

Comment: @ fyr When i try to execute the file  , message is **MSVCP100D.dll** _missing.Try re-installing the program_

Comment: There is a stackoverflow topic regarding this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668566/application-has-failed-to-start-because-msvcp100d-dll-was-not-found-reinstalling

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, Your code should be:

```
ofstream printer;
printer.open("lpt1");
```

I believe it's case sensitive(not sure "lpt1" or "LPT1"). Also, you'll need to write a page eject command.

EDIT:
LPT (Line Print Terminal) is name of the [parallel port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port) interface on IBM PC-compatible computers. Over the years, the parallel port interface has decreased use because of the rise of Universal Serial Bus.

In `DOS`, the parallel ports could be accessed directly on the command line. For example, the command `type c:\autoexec.bat > LPT1` would direct the contents of the `autoexec.bat` file to the printer port(recognized by the reserved word LPT1"). A `PRN` device was also available as an alias for LPT1.

`Microsoft Windows` still refers to the ports in this manner in many cases, though this is often fairly hidden.

In the `Linux` operating system the first `LPT` port is available via the filesystem as `/dev/lp0`.

To write to a printer, one should simply open the printer *as if it were a file* (the printer name is system-dependent; on Windows machines, it will be `lpt1` or `prn`, while on unix machines, it will be something like `/dev/lp`), then write whatever text has to be written.

Sample program could be as simple as:

```
std::ofstream print; 
print.open("LPT1");
if (!print)
    return 0;
print << data;
print.close();
```

Comment: Huh? "lpt1" is a filename, last I checked.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Everything is a file in Unix/Linux.

Comment: OK, and what does that have to do with Windows?

Comment: (Even on Unix/Linux, you can't just open a file "lpt1" and expect it to work. It would be in some device path like "/dev/lpt1".)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: It's one of reserved DOS device names, you cannot create a file named like this.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Hah, so it is! That's amazing! OK I'll remove the downvote but this answer _definitely_ needs fleshing out. And Unix/Linux still has nothing to do with it.

Comment: In any case, writing to LPTx or PRN is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @ Als When i try to execute the file , message is **MSVCP100D.dll** _missing.Try re-installing the program_ (I compiled in my pc and ran it somewhere else) [code which became a binary code](http://suhail03.my3gb.com/printc++.txt)

Answer (score 2):

How would the *file* stream know the difference between the name of a printer and a file that just happened to share the name of a printer? So no; you can't print to a printer by specifying the name of a printer.

Printing in Win32 is not a trivial task. You can't simply shove some characters at a printer; it needs to know about page layout, fonts, etc. Basically, the way to do it from Win32 is to "draw" to the printer with GDI commands. Beginner-level info can be [found here](http://www.stromcode.com/2008/03/02/cwin32-printing/).

---

Correction: apparently, you can stream output to the printer with a stream. However, it requires that the user has enabled some legacy functionality, so it isn't necessarily always available.

Comment: [Printing reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686805%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: -1 ... you cant have certain filenames twice in windows. See the reference to reserved filenames in my answer.

Comment: @fyr: Fair enough. But it's still not a good way to write to a file, since as you point out, it isn't guaranteed to actually work.